# Unit test for update the entity in Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am working in MVC application with EntityFramework. I writing microsoft unit test cases for the service method.(I don't have separate Data Access layer, I am accessing the DbContext object in service method itself).

In Service, I am updating my Customer details in entityframework, like below,

```
public void UpdateCustomer(Customer customer)
  {
      var existingCustomer = _dbCcontext.Customers.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == customer.Id);
      _dbCcontext.Entry(existingCustomer).CurrentValues.SetValues(customer);
      _dbCcontext.Entry(existingCustomer).Property(x => x.CreateByUserId).IsModified = false;
      _dbCcontext.Entry(existingCustomer).Property(x => x.CreateOnDateTime).IsModified = false;
  }
```

How to write unit test case for the above method?

Comment: You Can Use SqLite to Create the Database Tables as per your Model Class from your Entity Framework into InMemory of the System. Later On You Can provide the inputs needed by the Service Method to complete it. You can follow up the link

Answer (score 1):

To expand on kienct89's answer, there are several things that you can do to **unit test** your DbContext.

Even though you're not using a separate data access layer, I hope you're constructor injecting your DbContext into your service. If not, swap it out so that you are. Otherwise, you'll never be able to unit test it.

I have always used Moq as my mocking framework, but others have a similar function to accomplish what we're about to do.

```
[TestMethod]
public void WillUpdateCustomer()
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<DbContext>();
    var dbCustomer = new Customer { Id = 7 }; // add other properties too
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.Customers).Returns(new [] {dbCustomer}.AsQueryable());
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.SaveChanges()).Returns(1);

    var service = new CustomerService(mockContext.Object);
    var newCustomer = new Customer { Id = 7 }; // Have different properties

    service.UpdateCustomer(newCustomer);

    // Having dbCustomer in here might not be right. I'm thinking reference
    // as opposed to the values being equal on the object used in the call.
    mockContext.Verify(m => m.Update(dbCustomer), Times.Once());
}
```

What you're doing here is testing **your** code, and not allowing your test to fail because of anything to do with Entity Framework, or the database. That is what a Unit Test is for. With something like this, you should **always** have an Integration Test as well that is actually saving something to a test or dummy database to ensure that the code that is out of your hands does its job as well.

Most of the time, the Integration Test should live in a separate project, or have a different Test Category so that it won't be run by your Continuous Integration Server and constantly be hitting the database.

*Disclaimer* To go along with the comment on the last line, I haven't actually run this, but it is a good start for what you want to do. Any changes needed should be minor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Krillgar, I did the same way but it throws foreign key when updating.

Comment: Oh, try adding a Setup for SaveChanges. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use SqLite to Create the Database Tables as per your Model Class from your Entity Framework into InMemory of the System. Later On You Can provide the inputs needed by the Service Method to complete it. You can follow up the link to have an idea of how to get started.

[Unit Test](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/178635/Unit-Testing-Using-NUnit)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lara, Can I have any sample for it? because I am new to sql lite.